# Authorization for Microsoft App ID ... failed with status code Forbidden

Tags: botframework, slack-api

I have a well working bot that replies to messages in Slack and Skype. for my Slack users the bot also sends scheduled message every morning. I have a very simple code that once worked and than it started giving the "Authorization for Microsoft App ID ... failed with status code Forbidden" error .

Using latest bot framework NuGet Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3.5.
I triple checked I have my MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword in the app config file, also tried to specify explicitly in the code below. Same error.

Here is the test code that I thought should work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("https://slack.botframework.com"), "...", "...");
    var conversation = new ConversationAccount(true, "B0GRPT96X:T04EVT5HU:C0L57SCKY");
    var botAccount = new ChannelAccount("B0GRPT96X:T04EVT5HU", "grasp");
    IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
    message.From = botAccount;
    message.Conversation = conversation;
    message.ChannelId = "slack";
    message.Text = "some text";
    message.Locale = "en-En";
    connector.Conversations.SendToConversation((Activity)message);
}
```

If I call

```
bool t = MicrosoftAppCredentials.IsTrustedServiceUrl("https://slack.botframework.com");
```

it returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling to `MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl,...)` to add the Slack service url as a trusted host name. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/3a98a6b3d15962a57b5454bfb3f730d3588de3ef/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/MicrosoftAppCredentials.cs#L96) is the code of that method.